# Implementing DFT, inverse function not working properly

Tags: python, numpy, dft

I've implemented DFT and the inverse DFT Function according to the following formulas:

[image]

The DFT function works, but when testing the inverse on the output I don't get the original series.

```py
import numpy as np
import random

exp = np.exp
pi = np.pi

def mydft(X):
    n = len(X)
    out = []
    for k in range(n):
        temp = 0
        for i in range(n):
            temp += X[i] * exp(-2j*pi*k*i/n)
        out.append(temp)
    return np.array(out)

def myidft(X):
    n = len(X)
    out = []
    for k in range(n):
        temp = 0
        for i in range(n):
            temp += X[i] * exp(2j*pi*k*i/n)
        out.append(temp)
    return (1/n) * np.array(out)
```

### Testing

```py
orig = np.random.random(100)
trans = mydft(orig)

inv = myidft(trans)
print(np.allclose(inv, trans))
>>> False

print(np.allclose(trans, np.fft.fft(orig)))
>>> True
```

Since the original Function works and the modifications for the inverse are quite simple, I have no clue what went wrong!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your test be

```
print(np.allclose(inv, orig))
```

since

```
orig = myidft(mydft(orig))
```

because when I plot your DFT

[image: DFTandFFTcomparison]

and invDFT (of DFT of original signal)

[image: iDFTandiFFTcomparison]

compared to the [numpy FFT algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) the results are exactly the same. Your implementation seems right. Your test is wrong.